# What are near-identity transformations?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I've started a module on Dynamical systems and we're currently looking at Hopf bifurcations. Below is an exercise in our notes revolving around near identity transformations:

[image]

The notes seem to assume that we already know what a near identity transformation is and I haven't been able to find any resources that explain it further. I can find examples of them being used but nothing about what it is, where it comes from and why it's used.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain what they are or point me towards some resources that might explain them better. I'm not looking for a solution to this exercise. I just want to know what a near identity transformation does and it's purpose in this context.

Comment: Comparing with the definition found [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Differential_Equations/YD4PL0GZgOcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22near-identity%20transformation%22&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover), your transformation is of the form $$u=U+F(U,V),\quad v=V+G(U,V)$$ for homogeneous polynomials $F,G$. This fits squarely within their definition. (This doesn't explain -why- it's called a near-identity transformation, of course.)

Comment: Upon reflection, here's a guess: Per the above definition, $F$ and $G$ contain no constant or linear terms in $U,V$. As such, $u\approx U$ and $v\approx V$ near $U=V=0$ up to quadratic terms. So while this isn't really an identity transformation, it nevertheless behaves like the identity transformation in the vicinity of the origin.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and definitely helps. I think I'm getting a bit too bogged down in terminology, it's just a transformation for this exercise.

Comment: Well, it's not helpful for them to toss in terminology like that without giving context. (A footnote or some other parenthetical to the effect of "Hey, notice that the new variables look like the old ones near the origin" would be enough.)